# Keeping a WKWebView and it's UIViewController in the background running and accessible from multiple ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

> *Background: In order to make web requests to an API endpoint, I need to scrape a website and retrieve a token every 25-30 seconds. I'm doing this with a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) and injecting some custom JavaScript using [WKUserScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscript) to retrieve AJAX response headers containing the token. Please focus on the question specifically and not on this background information - I'm attempting this entirely for my own educational purposes.*

### Goal

I will have different 'model' classes, or even just other *UIViewControllers*, that may need to call the shared *UIViewController* to retrieve this token to make an authenticated request.

Maybe I might abstract this into one "Sdk" class. Regardless, this 'model' SDK class could be instantiated and used by any other *ViewController*.

### More info

I would like to be able to call the *UIViewController* of the *WKWebView* and retrieve some data. Unless I re-create it every 25 seconds, I need to run it in the background or share it. I would like to be able to run a *UIViewController* 'in the background' and receive some information from it once *WKWebView* has done it's thing.

I know there are multiple ways of communicating with another *ViewController* including delegation and segueing. However, I'm not sure that these help me keep the view containing the *WKWebView* existing in the background so I can call it's *ViewController* and have it re-perform the scrape. Delegation may work for normal code, but what about one that must have the view existing? Would I have to re-create this *WKWebView* dynamically each time a different model, or view controller, were to try and get this token?

[One post](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/container-view-controllers/) suggests utilising *ContainerViewControllers*. From this, I gather that in the 'master' *ViewController* (the one containing the other ones), I could place the hidden *WKWebView* to do it's thing and communicate to the child view controllers that way via delegation.

Another post suggests using *AppDelegate* and making it a shared service. I'm completely against using a **Singleton** as it is widely considered an anti-pattern. There must be another way, even if a little more complex, that helps me do what I want without resorting to this 'cheat'.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1) talks about communicating between multiple *ViewControllers*, but I can't figure out how this would be useful when something needs to stay running and executing things.

How about any other ways to do this? Run something in a background thread with a strong pointer so it doesn't get discarded? I'm using Xcode 9.2, Swift 4, and iOS 11. As I'm very new to iOS programming, any small code examples on this would be appreciated.

Comment: if your scraping it, it doesnt neccesarily have to render? which means you could just wrap it in a singleton like NSObject structure that handles all of the refreshing and any controller can access it

Comment: Thanks, I put in my message that I'm not looking to use a Singleton. That would be simple, and a last resort. I've added why I don't want to use a **Singleton** there :) Side-question, it would not need to render to perform the scraping etc??

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you need to make a call to get the token every 30 seconds, and you need that up to date token available for any view controller to use?

Comment: then still make a wrapper, as I stated and pass it between classes, it doesnt have to be a singleton, whichever pattern you choose its not going to work out loosely bound, least bound would probably be use a DB to store the last known key, make a wrapper and inject the context, save the key on every successful scrape, fetch the key every time something wants to use it

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani Yep. If it was just a standard HTTP request, I'd put this in a model class and then just use that wherever. Instead, I use a `WKWebView` and this of course needs a `ViewController` etc

Comment: it doesnt 'need' a uiviewcontroller if your never visually seeing it ?

Comment: How about defining a timer in the app delegate, that will trigger a notification. Define a method thats called when this notification is trigerred that makes the call, And up on success save the new token inside of an NSDefault string. When you want to fetch it from anywhere, just fetch the value inside of the NSDefault

Comment: @SeanLintern88 Thanks for your response - new to iOS dev. So you suggest creating and rendering the `WKWebView` programatically with (it's hidden attribute set to true), storing that in the DB and then pulling from there. Can you do this in a thread? I assumed a `UIViewController` was needed to talk to it.

Comment: kinda, you dont have to actually add the WKWebview to anything, so you dont need to set anything to hidden, just make a class of NSObject with a var webView: WKWebView, init it and there you have it, it will still work 100%, you will just never render it. the NSobject can be made from anywhere, maybe in your app delegate, and as long as you keep a ref to it, you can inject an NSManagedObject context or as stated simply us UserDefaults to store the key, anything that needs it can pull from the same persistence

Comment: @SeanLintern88 Great, thanks! Let me go give this a shot as it's taught me a good few things already. My only confusion is keeping a reference to it in AppDelegate, is this effectively making it a global var?

Comment: Looks like I've hit a stumbling block - **WKWebView must be in the view heirarchy** to work. So I can't just use it in the background :( [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169884/wkwebkit-javascript-execution-when-not-attached-to-a-view-hierarchy), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074768/wkwebview-is-not-loading-resources-when-not-presented)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `WKWebView` *must be in the view hierarchy* to use it. You must have added it as a sub view of an on-screen view controller.

This was fine for me. I added this off-screen so it was not visible. Hidden attribute might have worked as well. Either way you must call `addSubview` with it to make it work.

[There are some other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169884/wkwebkit-javascript-execution-when-not-attached-to-a-view-hierarchy) questions and answers here [which verify this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074768/wkwebview-is-not-loading-resources-when-not-presented)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way if you don't wish to use a singleton.

1- In the `DidFinishlaunchingWithOptions`, Make a timer that runs in the background and call a method inside the app delegate Called `FetchNewToken`.

2- In FetchNewToken, make the call needed and retrieve the new token (you can use alamofire or any 3rd library to make the call easier for you).

Up on successfully retrieving the token, save it in `NSUserDefaults` under the name `upToDateToken`

You can access this token anywhere from the application using `NSUserDefaults` and it will always be up to date.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not looking for the Singleton, it's widely regarded as an anti-pattern (and I do mention this in my question).

Comment: Again thanks Mohammad. Both Singleton and, seemingly, AppDelegate usage provide a global variable which I'm trying to avoid. However, if I can't get anything else working, I'll use it. So for now, leave your answer here and if I can't do anything else I'll use this and mark it as the answer :)